# XamDatetimeEditor calendar lost

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am working on a big application that relies on Infragistics objects to display info to the user (WPF, Infragistics suite Ver 11.2). Inside the XamDatagrid users can input some dates (internally it uses the XamDatetimeEditor) using either the keyboard or a calendar. Most of the times the calendar is there but sometimes, for no reason (and I've been debugging and checking exceptions) the calendars just disappear, specially when I reload the data (by pressing "Search" again).

I know there is not enough technical data nor code but I just wanted to know if somebody has faced similar issues with this grid/version and how (if you could) solved it.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you used a tool like Snoop to verify that the XamDateTimeEditor is still being used after reloading the data?

Comment: Hi Alhalama, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't install new apps on the machine the client provided for this development so I decided to find a workaround and after asking Infragistics directly I found this:  http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/105005/496450.aspx

Comment: I asked some questions on the post on the Infragistics forum to help me understand what is happening.